# call function only once from adapter if timer up in recyclerview?

Tags: android, time, countdowntimer

how to call recyclerview loading web service while count down timer finished? In this code `getAllResturant("")` function continuously auto calling. I want to call it only once if timer finish in recyclerview adapter. Below is my code:

```
TimerListAdapter(ArrayList<DashBoardListModel.Detail> resturantList,
                              Context context, String latitude, String longitude, long time) {
    this.resturantList = resturantList;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.response_time = time;

    lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    startUpdateTimer();

}

private void startUpdateTimer() {

    tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ResturantDashboardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dashboard_item, parent, false);
    return new ResturantDashboardViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ResturantDashboardViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ResturantDashboardViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final DashBoardListModel.Detail resturantDetails = resturantList.get(position);

    synchronized (lstHolders) {
        lstHolders.add(holder);
    }
    holder.setData(resturantDetails);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (6 > resturantList.size()) {
        return resturantList.size();
    } else {
        return 6;
    }
}

class ResturantDashboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView tv_resturantname, tvCloseAt, book_now, tvSeatLeft, tvSuburb, tvMinutes, tvSeconds, tvOutlets, tv_distance, tv_place, tv_rating, tvClosed, tvCostForTwo, tvOffer;
    DashBoardListModel.Detail mProduct;

    ResturantDashboardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvMinutes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
        tvSeconds = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
        tvOutlets = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOutlets);

    }

    public void setData(DashBoardListModel.Detail resturantDetails) {
        mProduct = resturantDetails;
        if (!mProduct.getRemainingTime().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            updateTimeRemaining(Long.parseLong(mProduct.getRemainingTime()));
        }
    }

    private void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {


        if (!mProduct.getRemainingTime().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
            String time = String.format("%02d", calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" +
                    String.format("%02d", calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":" +
                    String.format("%02d", calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(time.split(":"));
            long hour = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
            long min = Integer.parseInt(list.get(1));
            long sec = Integer.parseInt(list.get(2));


            long result = (hour * 60L * 60L * 1000L) + (min * 60L * 1000L) + (sec * 1000L);

            long timeDiff = result - response_time;


            timeDiff = 60000- timeDiff;

            if (timeDiff > 0) {
                int seconds = (int) (timeDiff / 1000) % 60;
                int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);

                tvMinutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes));
                tvSeconds.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds));

            } else {
                tmr.cancel();
                getAllResturant("");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `if(timeDiff == 0)`?

Comment: getAllResturant(""); this function is continuously calling which is defined in else condition

Comment: How can I call it only once?

Comment: you can add `boolean`. If `getAllResturant` is called, set the `boolean` as true, and use `if-else` condition to check.

Comment: Can you give me your solution as answer so that I can vote @JohnJoe

Comment: Declare "updateTimeRemaining" as synchronized like "private synchronized void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {"

Answer (score 0):

This might not a best approach, but you can try

```
int count = 0;

if (timeDiff > 0) {
        .....
    } else {
        if (count == 0) {
           getAllResturant("");
           count++
        }
           tmr.cancel();        
   }
```

Comment: Why do you call the time's cancel method in both branches instead of moving it out of the if?

Comment: @Zoe make sense. Thanks

Comment: its working for first time and after that this called function at 4 seconds remaining @JohnJoe

Comment: set the count as global